# What are the limitations of Ladybug's "Lucky Charm"?

Tags: powers, miraculous-ladybug

In *[Miraculous: Tales of Ladybug and Cat Noir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miraculous:_Tales_of_Ladybug_%26_Cat_Noir)*, Ladybug uses her "Lucky Charm" power as a sort of finishing move. Each time she uses it, the charm turns into a different object. In one episode*, it turns into another (normal) yo-yo. In another episode**, it turns into a power strip, but she doesn't plug anything into it--she just twirls it like her yo-yo. Specifically being a powerstrip wasn't useful; another yo-yo would have been just as effective.

Why doesn't the Lucky Charm turn into the same object more than once? Is that a limitation of its powers? Are there other limitations?

---

*I can't remember which episode.

**I think it's Ep. 15, "Puppeteer," but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per [the wiki](http://miraculousladybug.wikia.com/wiki/Lucky_Charm), one limitation is "she can only use it once before reverting back into her civilian form five minutes later". Outside of that, it's pretty clear that Ladybug has no control over the object which is summoned and that, while every object is useful for her purpose of defeating the villain, she does not necessarily know *how* it will helpful, and generally has to figure that out. You can pretty much chalk that up to the whim of [Ladybug Miraculous](http://miraculousladybug.wikia.com/wiki/Ladybug_Miraculous) or its creator. The current [list of summoned objects](http://miraculousladybug.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Lucky_Charm_objects) has no repeats, but that might simply be because it has not repeated itself yet.

Incidentally, *[Simon Says](http://miraculousladybug.wikia.com/wiki/Simon_Says)* is the episode where she turns it into another yo-yo, a non-magical one. The context of the episode was that Simon's power prevented her from using her magic yo-yo, but she was able to knock the cards out of his hands with the mundane one.